# How to use pyautogui on macOS to open the search bar?

Tags: python, macos, pyautogui

I'm having difficulty automating opening the search bar on Mac with Python. It's a combination of two keys to call up the search bar, and I don't know how to do it.

I've already tried using

```
pyautogui.hotkey("command", "spaceBar")
pyautogui.write("safari")
pyautogui.press("return")
```

I've tried several ways (space-bar; space and so on) but it only types "safari" within my editor

How to open the search bar and type "safari"?

Answer (score 1):

"space" is correct key. Don't use "spaceBar". Refer https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#keyboard-keys.

I don't know why `hotkey()` is not working but what it does is `keyDown()` given keys and `keyUp()` them in reverse order.

Just did what `hotkey()` does but with `keyDown()` and `keyUp()` and that seems to work. Also `press()` is just `keyDown()` followed by `keyUp()` for single key.

```py
import pyautogui
pyautogui.keyDown("command")
pyautogui.press("space")
pyautogui.keyUp("command")
pyautogui.write("safari")
pyautogui.press("return")
```